# Passing object as parameter

Tags: java, object, parameters, extends

I cant seem to get the following to work: I got this method checkEnemyHealth() which takes care of the health of an enemy by changing the sprites and adding kills etc. However, I need to change the kills of a specific Playertank object, so I tried the following code:

```
public void collisionOccured(GameItem collidedItem)
{
    if(collidedItem instanceof Playertank) //Botsing met player
    {
        enemyHealth = 0.0;      
    }       
    if (collidedItem instanceof Weapon) //Botsing met wapen
    {
        lowerEnemyHealth(Weapon.weaponDamage);
        System.out.println("loweredddd");
    }
    if ((collidedItem instanceof Weapon) || (collidedItem instanceof Playertank))
    {
    checkEnemyHealth((GameItem)collidedItem);
    }
}

    public void checkEnemyHealth(GameItem collidedItem)
{
    if (enemyHealth >= (2.0/3.0 * startupEnemyHealth))
    {
        this.setFrame(0); //Green Enemy
        this.setEnemyStage(0);
    }
    else if (enemyHealth < (2.0/3.0 * startupEnemyHealth) && enemyHealth >= (1.0/3.0 * startupEnemyHealth))
    {
        this.setFrame(1); //Orange Enemy
        this.setEnemyStage(1);
    }
    else if (enemyHealth < (1.0/3.0 * startupEnemyHealth) && enemyHealth > 0)
    {
        this.setFrame(2); //Red Enemy
        this.setEnemyStage(2);
    }
    else if (enemyHealth <= 0 && (getEnemyStage() != 3))
    {
        setImage("/images/death.png", 27, 33); //Dead enemy     
        enemyOnDeath();
        if (collidedItem instanceof Playertank)
        {
            ((Playertank)collidedItem).raisePlayerKills(1); 
            mygame.setKillsonDashboard(((Playertank)collidedItem).getPlayerKills());
            ((Playertank)collidedItem).raisePlayerLandmines(1);
            mygame.setLandminesonDashboard(((Playertank)collidedItem).getPlayerLandmines());
        }
        mygame.setTimer(10, 33, this);
    }
    printHealth();
    System.out.println(this.getEnemyStage());
}
```

However, I also need to do the raisePlayerKills() even when the instance is a Weapon. I cant seem to find the solution.

Some more info:

```
Playertank.java creates the gameplayer and extends GamePlayer.java
GamePlayer.java extends MoveableGameItem.java
Enemytank.java extends MoveableGameItem.java
MoveableGameItem.java extends GameItem.java
```

I hope its enough to solve this issue,
Thx in advance Flame

Comment: The method doesn't return anything. Do you mean you get a NullPointerException?

Comment: `2.0/3.0 * startupEnemyHealth` is not a good way to do multiply by fractions. `2 * startupEnemyHealth / 3.0` will return 200 for startupEnemyHealth 300, while your version will return an approximation.

Comment: why's that btw? i'd say 2*5/3 is the same as 2/3*5 :) ofcourse i'm not a java compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cast doesn't do anything: `checkEnemyHealth((GameItem)collidedItem);`
 -- collidedItem is already of type `GameItem`.

This downcast is guaranteed to fail: `checkEnemyHealth((Playertank)collidedItem);` since I assume `Playertank` is not a subclass of `Weapon`, nor vice versa.

Overall, the exact code you posted cannot raise a `NullPointerException` since there is no codepath that would invoke `checkEnemyHealth` with `null` -- and that's the only way to get an NPE after 'beforreee', but not after 'afterrrr'. So let me ask you this: what exception DOES your code throw? I suspect a `ClassCastException`:

```
((Playertank)collidedItem).raisePlayerKills(1);
```

This is an unchecked dowcast to Playertank.

Comment: it returns

java.lang.ClassCastException, sorry for the misunderstanding i didnt say it returned a nullpointer, just a null :)

Comment: Whenever your code throws an exception, always provide the stacktrace when posting a question. It is ALWAYS the key diagnostic information.

Comment: So, do you understand what I said? You cannot just go ahead and downcast to Playertank. What if it's not a `Playertank`?

Comment: im getting it im getting it, it seems like my method will never work because i 'must' get the ((Playertank)collidedItem).raisePlayerKills(1); to work, even when the collided item is a Weapon. In that case the parameter is a Weapon object (if i'd put checkEnemyHealth((Weapon)collidedItem);)

Comment: So i need to get a method which retrieves the Playertank object at any time. I tried including the checkEnemyHealth() in the collisionOccured() but that became a mess and it would check over and over again hmm...

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest walking through the code in a debugger. This will most likely show you what is null. It appears that collided item is null. Are you sure you are passing an instantiated object to the method checkEnemyHealth?

Comment: (Playertank)collidedItem) appears to be null, and as far as i know the Playertank is always instantiated hmm...